# Linq to Xml - Input String

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq to Xml to parse some xml messages coming from a legacy system. One of the messages is coming in as Name / Value pairs.  So I am doing the lookup by name and then trying to get the equivalent value.  However, when the Value is blank (`<Value/>`) my code is throwing the error `Input string was not in a correct format.`

I am trying to figure out the best way to solve this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated (Trying to fill property with nullable int type int?).

Code Example:

```
myRecord.myField= xdoc.Descendants("Information")
                        .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Name") == "myField")
                        .Select(x => (int?)x.Element("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
```

XML Snippet:

```
    <Information>
      <Name>myField</Name>
      <Value />
    </Information>
```

Always appreciate the feedback / input.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When element is empty, then it's value is `String.Empty` which cannot be parsed as integer. So, you should treat this case manually:

```
myRecord.myField = xdoc.Descendants("Information")
                       .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Name") == "myField")
                       .Select(x => x.Element("Value"))
                       .Select(v => (v == null || v.IsEmpty) ? null : (int?)v)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Will throw NullReferenceException when there is no such an element (what probably is not a case here, but is worth to know)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek nope, it will not This condition will handle missing element `(v == null || v.IsEmpty)`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek actually yes :) your comment appeared just after I updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

*There is already correct answer provided, but I think that a bit more explanation would be helpful.*

The whole thing is about [`XElement` to `Nullable<T>` explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340386.aspx). Watch out that example to see, what's going on:

```
XElement element = null;
// returns null
int? value = (int?)element;

element = new XElement("test", 1);
// returns 1
value = (int?)element;

element = new XElement("test");
// throws FormatException
value = (int?)element;
```

`(int?)xElementInstance` returns `null` only, where element is `null`. Otherwise, int parsing is processed, which throws an exception, whenever `XElement.Value` is not an integer (like in out case, when there is no `Value`, so it's like `int.Parse(String.Empty)`).

You have to check `is XElement set` and `does XElement has value` before conversion:

```
if (element == null)
    return null;
else if (element.IsEmpty)
    return null
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value))
    return null
else
    return (int?)element;
```

What can be easily done using inline statement:

```
(element == null || element.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value) ? null : (int?)element)
```

To sum up, following code do what you want - takes `int?` from XElement, event when element has no value:

```
element = new XElement("test");
// returns null
value = element == null || element.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value) ? null : (int?)element;
```

Comment: If you use `XElement.Parse("<Value></Value>")`, then `IsEmpty` will return `false`, but the `Value` will return an empty string, and the conversion will throw a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static int? ToInt32(this XElement element)
   {
      if (element == null) return null;
      if (element.IsEmpty) return null;

      // If the element is declared as <Value></Value>,
      // IsEmpty will be false, but the value will be an empty string:
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value)) return null;

      return XmlConvert.ToInt32(element.Value);
   }
}

myRecord.myField = doc.Descendants("Information")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Name") == "myField")
   .Select(x => x.Element("Value").ToInt32()).FirstOrDefault();
```